# mysql query to if exists update else insert query without unique id

Tags: php, mysql

I need a mysql query to  update data if exists, else insert data without unique id.

Actually i have a table like this

```
    id  company_ID  Employee_ID Name        Relationship    Dob     Age Gender       
    1   EMPL        00001       Choodamani  Spouse      11-Aug-66   49  Female            
    2   EMPL        00001       Komala      Mother      30-Oct-39   76  Female            
    3   EMPL        00001       Varshini    Daughter    29-Apr-04   11  Female            
    4   EMPL        00001       Vasudevan   Employee    15-Jul-62   53  Male    
    5   EMPL        00002       Siddharth   Son         1-Jun-00    15  Male              
    6   EMPL        00002       Poongavanam Mother      21-Oct-39   76  Female            
    7   EMPL        00002       Aruna       Spouse      16-Sep-68   47  Female            
    8   EMPL        00002       Abirami     Daughter    7-May-97    18  Female            
    9   EMPL        00002       Murali      Employee    7-Oct-67    48  Male
```

if have insert a data like this,

```
        id  company_ID  Employee_ID Name        Relationship    Dob     Age Gender       
        1   EMPL        00001       Choodamani  Spouse      11-Aug-70   45  Female            
        2   EMPL        00001       Nirmal      Son      30-Oct-39   76  Female
```

In above that i have update first employee `Dob` and `Age`,
In second id 2 you can see am insert new data for same employee

Here what i need is , update a data if exist else insert as new data without unique, I need a query for this

In this table i did'nt have any unique field, `id` field alone has `primary ke`y and `auto increment`

presently am using this query to insert

```
INSERT INTO employee (company_id, employee_id, name, relationship, dob, age, gender) VALUES ('$company_id','$employee_id', '$name', '$relationship', '$dob', '$age', '$gender')
```

Comment: are you using php too

Comment: is like studying your table how can different people share the same employment id

Comment: You can have several sams same age so good luck

Comment: actually this insert has been done while importing excel sheet

Comment: Dont have an age column

Comment: I would advice you to make the employee id unique then I can write some sql for you

Comment: Is that possible to have same Employee_ID for different employees? If yes and there is no other way to distinguish (a combination two or more keys) employees, it won't be possible.

Comment: Ash they arent employees

Comment: In fact one could be a dog

Comment: if i make employee_id unique, while importing excel sheet with other two family members from the same employee family, thats makes the data not to insert

Comment: is there any other way

Comment: If there's no unique ID, how can you tell if the data exists or not?

Comment: @DrewPierce : Thanks for the hint. I didn't notice it. So I guess we can make a unique key with name and employee_id combination, right?

Comment: ya right, @ Drewpierce please give me a code

Comment: You cant. You have 2 friends named Sam born on same day

Comment: @ash_8247 Yes, that seems right.

Comment: It is not solvable but funny

Comment: i mean the combination of name and employee_id or name and dob

Comment: @ExCrin Please do check whether there's an entry in the table that matches these three fields. Employee_id. name and relation. If yes edit that row, else insert as a new row. Do you need the code for the same?

Comment: @ash_8247 can you give me a code

Comment: We just say hey bob your name is robert

Comment: Before that have a look at the Barmar's answer.

Comment: These work fine for relatively small sets of data. The SSA wouldn't design a system like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique key on the two columns `employee_id`, `name`, and `relationship`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX empid_name ON employee (employee_id, name, relationship);
```

I added `relationship` to the key in case an employee has a son with the same name as their father, for example.

Then you can use `INSERT INTO employee ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` to either add or update a row depending on whether it already exists.

Comment: He all but wrote it for you Ex

Comment: You already have the `INSERT` code in the question, it should work as you wrote it.

Comment: Problem is if employees dad is bob and in comes friend bob you just blew away data

Comment: Ok brother or sister who had a sex change

Answer (score 1):

The only distinguishing factor that you stated in the comments is the name + employee_id. Here's some code demonstrating this:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    company_ID varchar(32),
    Employee_ID  INT(11),
    Name varchar(32),
    Relationship varchar(32),
    Dob varchar(32),
    Age INT(11),
    Gender varchar(32),
    UNIQUE KEY employee_id_name (Employee_ID, Name)
);

INSERT INTO employee VALUES

    (1,   'EMPL',        00001,       'Choodamani',  'Spouse',      '11-Aug-66',   49,  'Female'),            
    (2,   'EMPL',        00001,       'Komala',      'Mother',      '30-Oct-39',   76,  'Female'),           
    (3,   'EMPL',        00001,       'Varshini',    'Daughter',    '29-Apr-04',   11,  'Female'),            
    (4,   'EMPL',        00001,       'Vasudevan',   'Employee',    '15-Jul-62',   53,  'Male'),    
    (5,   'EMPL',        00002,       'Siddharth',   'Son',         '1-Jun-00',    15,  'Male'),              
    (6,   'EMPL',        00002,       'Poongavanam', 'Mother',      '21-Oct-39',   76,  'Female'),            
    (7,   'EMPL',        00002,       'Aruna',       'Spouse',      '16-Sep-68',   47,  'Female'),           
    (8,   'EMPL',        00002,       'Abirami',     'Daughter',    '7-May-97',    18,  'Female'),            
    (9,   'EMPL',        00002,       'Murali',      'Employee',    '7-Oct-67',    48,  'Male');


INSERT INTO employee (company_id, employee_id, name, relationship, dob, age, gender) VALUES ('EMPL',        00001,       'Choodamani',  'Spouse',      '11-Aug-70',   45,  'Female')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE company_id=VALUES(company_id), employee_id=VALUES(employee_id), name=VALUES(name), relationship=VALUES(relationship), dob=VALUES(dob), age=VALUES(age), gender=VALUES(gender);

INSERT INTO employee (company_id, employee_id, name, relationship, dob, age, gender) VALUES ('EMPL',        00001,       'Nirmal',      'Son',      '30-Oct-39',   76,  'Female')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE company_id=VALUES(company_id), employee_id=VALUES(employee_id), name=VALUES(name), relationship=VALUES(relationship), dob=VALUES(dob), age=VALUES(age), gender=VALUES(gender);
```

[Output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23f59/1)

And in PHP use:

```
INSERT INTO employee (company_id, employee_id, name, relationship, dob, age, gender) VALUES ('$company_id','$employee_id', '$name', '$relationship', '$dob', '$age', '$gender') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE company_id=VALUES(company_id), employee_id=VALUES(employee_id), name=VALUES(name), relationship=VALUES(relationship), dob=VALUES(dob), age=VALUES(age), gender=VALUES(gender)
```